# how to use modulefinder replace_path in __init__.py to import a package

Tags: python, import, path, package

in directory mydir I have:

```
 x.py with:

     import mypackage.mymodule

 mymodule.py:
    def module()
 __init__.py
```

I do not want to create a sub directory mypackage in mydir and have another __init__.py there. I know it is not recommended my reasons are beyond the scope here.

I was trying to modify the module name and path using the modulefinder. I did not find a good documentation on the subject;

I created a file:

```
  mymod.py:

    import mypackage.mymodule
    import x

and from \__init__.py:

        import modulefinder
        finder = modulefinder.ModuleFinder('/fullpath/mydir',0,['x.py'],['mypackage.mymodule',(('mypackage/mymodule','mymodule')
        finder.run_script('mymod')

I also tried:

    __init__.py:

      import modulefinder
      modulefinder.AddPackagePath('mypackage','/fullpath/mydir')
```

A third method I tried was to modify the sys.modules myself. Also didn't work for me; I got a set error on the key().

can you specify for each method why it did not work and the right way to twick?

Comment: have you tried the explicit relative import: `from . import mymodule`?